# Java Naming Convention for Variable Type Clarity

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

I'm new to core Java so I'm trying to start off in the right direction.

I'm trying to determine if there is an accepted convention for using '*type abbreviations*' for variable naming.

For instance

```
pulic class ShirtExample {

// String variables 

String foo = new String("String Variable");

//vs

String strFoo = new String("String Variable");

    // Array variables

    Shirt [] shirts = {
        new Shirt(),
        new Shirt(),
        new Shirt()
    };

//vs 

    Shirt [] arrShirts = {
        new Shirt(),
        new Shirt(),
        new Shirt()
    };

}
```

Comment: Ah, Hungarian notation. I thought you died when strongly typed languages were invented, but you survived. When IDEs came around, I thought you were gone for sure. But yet, you still won't go away...

Comment: It's called Systems Hungarian notation, and it's a terrible idea. For starters, it doesn't tell you anything not already stated in the declaration (i.e. redundancy, with all the associated pitfalls). There's also Apps Hungarian which is less stupid because the prefixes convey something Java's type system doesn't solve better, though it's still fugly.

Comment: @delnan ... :-) Okay maybe Hungarian notation was a doomed example. Are there suggested guidelines other than common sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stay away from any conventions for naming variables, especially Hungarian notation or the like.  The names should represent the intent of what you are storing.

Comment: NB Conventions can set good guidelines for how to capture intent better. Not all conventions are stupid rules adding needless bureaucracy.

Comment: Thank you @tjg184 ... I'll take your advice here.

Comment: @delnan Just so it's clear, I'm not indicating guidelines are bad.  I have worked on several teams now where we spent more time debating what to prefix variables with versus actually making the code easy to read.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The only time I've seen type-related naming conventions was at a previous employer, and it wasn't for Java.

At one point I'm sure including type information in variable names was useful, but in my personal opinion that time is long past. As tjg184 mentioned in his answer, the name should be descriptive of what the variable holds. Following that advice will accurately communicate type without you explicitly codifying it for 99% of your variables. For everything else, a good IDE (or quick text search if you're developing in something like VIM) will tell you the variable type.

Comment: +1 Thank you Eric ... per your suggestion I'll accept tjg184's response.

Answer (score 1):

Plurals are generally used for collections and arrays but type signifiers are generally not used when naming variables